# How to set up DNS when connecting to two networks?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, centos6

I have a linux machine with two network interfaces. They are both connected to local networks -- one is `192.168.*.*`, the other is `10.*.*.*`.

The `192.168.*.*` network is completely private and does not have internet access. The `10.*.*.*` network does have internet access.

Currently, I can do external ping's and the names will resolve

```
ping google.com
```

However, when I try to ping a machine name on the `192.168.*.*` network, the name will not resolve

```
ping computer-name
ping computer-name.domain
ping computer-name.domain.local
```

If I specify an IP address, it will resolve

```
ping 192.168.x.x
```

How can I set up DNS settings so that the machine names on the private local network will resolve, but I can still resolve external addresses?

I am using Centos6.

Answer (score 3):

In situations like this you usually need to setup a DNS resolver that will forward to various upstream DNS servers based on the namespace.  You can do this [with DNSMasq](https://superuser.com/questions/690751/use-vpn-dns-only-for-domains-matching-a-pattern-otherwise-continue-to-use-isp-d/690760#690760), [Bind](https://serverfault.com/a/718162/984) and other DNS servers.

Comment: Both networks have DNS servers.  The problem is that neither DNS can resolve addresses on the other network and only one of the DNS servers can resolve external names. Is there a way to point to multiple DNS servers?  Or to somehow direct certain requests (like all `domain.local` lookups) to a certain DNS?

Comment: no...on your machine, you need to install bind and setup forwarders for each zone, then set your machine to point to localhost (bind)

Comment: follow his links.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get this working by modifying my `/etc/resolv.conf` file

```
domain privatedomain
search privatedomain publicdomain.com
nameserver 192.168.10.15
nameserver 10.10.1.15
```

The `privatedomain` is the local `192.168.*.*` network domain name.  The `publicdomain.com` is the domain name for the `10.*.*.*` network with internet access.

It can now resolve all these requests correctly

```
ping computer.privatedomain
ping computer
ping computer2.publicdomain.com
ping google.com
```

The only downside to this is that when I try to resolve a name that isn't reachable from the private domain, there is a noticeable delay.  For example:

```
ping google.com
```

I imagine it's because it's first attempting to resolve the name via the first nameserver on the `privatedomain`, which will eventually timeout, and then goes to the second nameserver which is able to resolve it.